# Would a custom mod built for RakNet be automatically usable with Unity?

Tags: unity, networking, security

Context: I'm interesting in developing a security module for servers that handle mobile games, and I'd like it to be usable by the most people possible. So I'm trying to decide what server software I want to build it for.

I'm looking at RakNet, and it's appealing because it's available two ways: independently and as part of the networking solution of Unity3D. So it's software that gets used by developers who want to use Unity3D as well as those who don't.

My question: if I create a modification that implements my security system inside RakNet, will that solution be automatically compatible with Unity also?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Unity usage/implementation of RakNet is not open to the end user of Unity.